# Verbs related to learning or teaching

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова, глаголы, синонимы, вид

there.
May you explain me differences between following verbs in detail?!
(Attention: For God's sake, PLEASE, Don't match them up with English words like: study, learn, teach, etc. Just please try to define them or the action and and also look to them from grammar point, Please make for every verb at least two samples!)
(Also please pair them based on being imperfective/perfective and explain me differences even in that aspect too)

1) учи́ть

2) вы́учить

3) изуча́ть

4) изучи́ть

5) учи́ться

6) занима́ться

7) заучи́ть

8) научи́ть

9) выу́чивать

10) зау́чивать

11) научи́ться

12) обуча́ться

13) обучи́ться

If you remember any other verb which is related to this subject, please write it down here too!
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Would you like the verbs to be explained in English? If so, one cannot avoid matching them up with English words like: study, learn , teach, etc.

Comment: Related question: [How can “to teach” and “to learn” be translated to Russian?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/170/how-can-to-teach-and-to-learn-be-translated-to-russian). Actually, one may even say ‘duplicate’.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is not showing the effort. You just posted a list of words and ask us to write an explanatory dictionary entry for each of them. Are you writing a text-book and want us to do your job? This help article has some tips how to make your question great: [How to ask](https://russian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

1) учи́ть - imperfective

(1) - to teach

Usage: учить кого-то чему-то, учить кого-то что-то делать

- Учить детей албанскому - to teach children Albanian language
- Учить детей петь и танцевать - to teach children singing and dancing

Note that 
* the student is in accusative, the topic is in dative.
* Only in some special cases you can omit the student, the topic, or both.

Also, учить means to teach somebody how to do something or just to teach somebody to do something. More examples:

- жизнь научила меня не поддаваться отчаянию
- вас не учили называть незнакомых людей на вы?
- меня учили, что пожилым надо уступать место в автобусе (note "учили, что")

(2) - to learn (some subject, topic)

Examples:
* Я учу историю - I learn history.  Here the topic is in accusative.
* Учи албанский! - learn Albanian language!

But you cannot say 
* "я учу шахматы" (chess playing is a skill, not a topic) - correct: я учусь играть в шахматы
* "я учу муравьёв" meaning that you are study ants by observations, experiments etc. - correct: я изучаю муравьёв.

2. Научить - perfective of учить (1).
3. Учиться - учить (1) себя:

   - я учусь петь
   - я учусь математике
   - котёнок учится ходить
4. Научиться - perfective of учиться.

5-6. изуча́ть (imperf.)/изучи́ть (perf.) - to study

- изучить план местности - to study the map deeply
- я изучаю собак - I study dogs (i.e. study them with observation, experiments etc., rather than from textbooks or with a teacher.)

7-8. выучить/заучить (perf.) -

(1) to learn some topic/text. "Заучить" has some negative connotation, meaning just to memorize something, without understanding.

- Вася заучил доказательство теоремы Пифагора - Vasya remembers the proof word by word, but hardly understand it.
- Вася выучил доказательство теоремы Пифагора - Vasya knows the proof.
- Я выучил русский - ok.
- "Я заучил русский" - this sentence is wrong.  Можно заучить текст, но не язык или предмет.

(2) Also, выучить кого-либо чему-либо is to learn an animal some trick, or to learn human in the same manner.

- Выучил собаку давать лапу
- Выучил собаку командам "голос!", "сидеть!" и "лежать!"

Maybe there are other meanings of выучить.

9-10. Заучивать/выучивать - imperfective of заучить/выучить (1).

Answer (score 3):

учиться, учить, выучить, заучить or whatever.

The root of them is "учить" (to study or to learn in English), and these verbs differ only with the prefixes (вы-,за-,на-). Each different prefix slightly change the meaning of its verb.

"выучить" and "заучить" show some final results you have succeeded while studying.
*Я выучил/заучил пять новых слов.
I have learnt/memorized five new words*.

"изучить" means you have obtained essential knowledge by researching some subject of your interest, not indicating the steps you have taken to achieve that. "Изучить" sounds more seriously than simply "учить" I would say, scientifically.

*Я изучил устройство кофеварки от А до Я.
I have learnt the operation principles of a coffeemaker from A to Z.

За два года я изучил грамматику русского языка.
It took me two years to master Russian grammar.* (No need to say that you had to learn words and grammatical rules, you've just done it as a whole and that's all.)

"Научить" means teaching something to someone and definitely having result in that.
*Он научил меня рисованию комиксов.
He has taught me how to draw comics.

Он учил меня рисованию комиксов.
He was teaching me how to draw comics.*

"Заниматься" is idiomatic, it says that at the moment you're busy with something. If you omit the reason of your occupation, then studying is implied.

*У меня нет времени, я занимаюсь.
I've no time, I'm studying.*

"Обучаться" or "Обучиться" indicate professional training.
*Их обучали кройке и шитью.
They were being trained to be a dressmaker.*

Answer (score 2):

Ещё можно сказать: **Зубрить**

- Вызубрить таблицу умножения.
- Ты, зубрил что ли?

Зубрить, означает учить что-либо тяжело запоминающееся, очень грубым, агрессивным способом.

Например, когда читаешь художественную литературу, Гоголя или Пушкина, можно сказать что материал пройден и ты с ним знаком.

Но когда "зубришь", ты можешь воспроизвести материал 1 в 1. И обычно это не связано с каким-либо элегантным способом запоминания, усвоения материала.

Непрерывный, можно даже сказать "тупой" повтор материала. Как молитвы.

Вызубренный материал проходит через временную память несколько раз, оседая в постоянной.

Вероятно, начной основой для зубрёшки могут быть работы [Шенона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD,_%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4) по временной памяти.

Смотри также [Интервальные повторения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)