# Help translating these time-related collocations into Russian

Tags: перевод

I'm looking for Russian equivalents for these time-related English collocations. Perhaps someone can help me?

1) to spend time

2) to waste time on something

3) to make time for something/someone

4) to save time

5) to have time for something

6) to kill or pass time

7) to take one's time

8) to be on time

9) Just in time

10) Have a hard or rough time with something

11) it's about time (finally!)

12) to run out about time

Many thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly, asking for lists-of-words is discouraged here. For instance [this question](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/7280/551) was closed as "too broad".

Comment: Well, people ultimately answered anyway. I did try to find this information elsewhere before crowdsourcing. It seems, at the very least, silly for this post to be disallowed while at the same time 12 individual posts would be permitted, as that's just inefficient.

Comment: Usually such posts look like: "I don't understand why these (a, b, c, etc.) expressions are different, because they all have the same English translation. What I am missing?".

Answer (score 2):

Note: when I wrote this answer, I didn't look at the other people's answers.

1) to spend time - провести время

2) to waste time on something - зря потратить время на что-то

3) to make time for something/someone - найти время на что-то/для кого-то

4) to save time - сэкономить время

5) to have time for something - иметь время на что-то (у него есть время на футбол)

6) to kill or pass time - убить время

7) to take one's time - занять чьё-то время

8) to be on time - прибыть/прийти вовремя

9) Just in time - точно вовремя, точно в нужное время

10) Have a hard or rough time with something - don't know how to translate this one

11) it's about time (finally!) - (наконец, наконец-то) настало время

12) to run out about time - don't know the meaning on English

Comment: can be also 3) выделить время 5) найти время на что-то, 10) испытывать трудности с чем-то 11) пришло время 12) run out of time? закончить время: ваше время закончилось, время вышло (ex. время на раздумье вышло)

Answer (score 2):

An addendum to the answers already given:

1) to spend time

"Провести время" would work in some contexts, e.g.:

- "While in jail I've spent quite some time in isolation" - *Я **провёл много времени** в изоляторе, пока сидел*.

In other contexts your best bet is an imperfect verb, often with "по-" prefix:

- "I need to spend some time with a good book on the subject" - *Мне бы не мешало **почитать** хорошую книгу по теме*.
- "I would like to spend some time alone" - *Я хотел бы **побыть** в одиночестве*.

6) to kill or pass time

"to do something to pass time" can also become "со скуки" or "от нечего делать":

- "Guards were playing poker to pass time" - *Охранники **от нечего делать** играли в покер*.

7) to take one's time

actually mistranslated in the other answer, this would be "не спешить, не торопиться" or even "без спешки":

- "Jack took his time to make a perfect headshot from a perfect hiding place" - *Джэк исполнил **не спеша** идеальный выстрел в голову из идеального укрытия*.

10) Have a hard or rough time with something

Daria's "испытывать трудности с чем-то" correctly conveys the meaning, but could sound too formal. "Не получаться", "не выходить", "не справляться" work in wider range of contexts, like:

- "I have hard time solving this puzzle" - ***у меня не получается** решить эту головоломку*, but also: *эта головоломка **мне не даётся***

In other cases (the activity is difficult but successful) you'd need "едва справляться", "едва получаться" etc:

- "I have hard time hiding the pregnancy" - *Мне **едва удаётся** скрывать, что я беременна*.

Another useful idiom for this one is "с (большим) трудом":

- "I've had hard time solving this puzzle" - *Эту головоломку я решил **с большим трудом***

In yet other cases you'd just need to negate a reflexive verb:

- "I have hard time sleeping at night" - *По ночам мне не спится* (but *Мне не удаётся заснуть* works too).

11) it's about time (finally!)

- *Давно пора!*

Answer (score 1):

1. Тратить время.
2. Тратить время на что-либо.
3. Найти время на что-либо.
4. Сэкономить время.
5. Иметь время на что либо.
6. Убить время (to spend a lot of time).
7. **
8. Быть вовремя.
9. Как раз вовремя.
10. Иметь плохое или неприятное время с кем-то.
11. Дело во времени.
12. **

Translation of these phrases is more about semantic meaning unlike direct translation.

** I confused to translate these phrases despite that Russian is my native language.

Good luck.

Comment: 7. `Тратить/занимать чье-то время`  12. `Не успеть вовремя`