# I'm very confuse with this word "учить"?

Tags: словоупотребление, узус

I saw this word from my Russian friend, `"учить".`  I confuse in this
word. teach or learn?  I try to google translate it. it show "teach".
What's the real meaning of this?

Comment: You might find this useful: [How can “to teach” and “to learn” be translated to Russian?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/170/551)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

both

Вася учит физику - Vasya learns/studies physics

Вася учит студентов - Vasya teaches students.

IIRC, there were questions about this word already.

Google Translate gave me not one but four translations: teach, learn, instruct, train.

Comment: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/170/how-can-to-teach-and-to-learn-be-translated-to-russian?rq=1

Comment: Vasya teaches physics - Вася *преподаёт* физику.

Answer (score 5):

It technically means both "to learn" and "to teach someone".

I learn Russian - Я учу русский
I teach you Russian- Я учу тебя русскому

But notice that when you want to say:
I love to teach - Я люблю учить
I love to learn - Я люблю учиться

Answer (score 0):

If the object after the verb *учить* is something to be learned/studied/memorized, then the verb means *to study/learn/memorize.*

If the object of the verb is a more or less intelligent being (group of such beings) who is (are) to learn from you, then it's *to teach/train/instruct*: *учить детей решать задачи* to teach children how to solve problems, *учить собаку прыгать через барьер* to train the dog to jump the barrier.

The verb may have a figurative meaning: «учить робота разговаривать» (*lit.* to teach the robot how to talk; actually, program it's voice software), or «учить самолеты летать» (a line from a once famous song about test pilots, to train airplanes in flying). However, in these cases, we "pretend" that robots and planes are intelligent beings that can be taught.